# Different alignment for text in a row of table

Tags: tables

I used the following code for generating a table:

```
\begin{tabular}{p{3cm} p{3.5cm} p{7cm}}
Parameter& Value & Remark      \\  
\hline \hline
     $\alpha$       & $1[-]$         & Reference angle.          \\
    \hline
     $\alpha_{\scaleto{1}{3.5pt}}$   & $\beta_{\scaleto{1}{3.5pt}}$     &Inflow angle.  \\
    \hline
    $\delta$        & $\num{0.5894}c = \num{0.59475} \, mm$ $\to $ $\num{9.87}  / c_{ax} = \num{5.874}$       & $-$           \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

I want to have center alignment for first and second column and left alignment for the third column.
Also I wish to have center alignment for the entry in third column and fourth row i.e., `-` (Please note that the length shown here is shorter than that in the attached image).
Can someone please help me achieve this?

I have attached an image describing the output of the above code:
[image]

Comment: `\begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3cm} >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3.5cm} p{7cm}}` to center the first and second column and `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` to center the entry of the last cell.

Comment: Does "mm"  in the last row of the second column refer to milli meter? If so, `\SI{0.59475}{\mm}`might be the better choice.

Comment: Is there a reason for stretching the width of the first column to 3cm? Why not simply use a `c` type column instead?